# Getting _register_s3_control_events() Error

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

I am trying to read a csv from an S3 bucket using my jupyter notebook. I have previously read this csv before and had no issues but now am receiving an error.

Here is the code I am running:

```
import pandas as pd
list = pd.read_csv(r's3://analytics/wordlist.csv')
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
An error was encountered:
_register_s3_control_events() takes 2 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

I thought it may be the S3 bucket permissioning but it is public to my organization and so shouldn't be the issue.
Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use boto to import the csv from s3. Boto is a python library for AWS.

By the way, this should work:

```py
import boto
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('s3://bucket....csv')
```

If you are on python 3.4+, you need:

```
import boto3
import io
import pandas as pd
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket', Key='key')
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the second example and it seems to have worked. Still unclear as to why my way suddenly stopped working, I've been using Python 3.7 for a while now